# No such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".contact-button link-phone"} selenium in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I'm trying to get information from a website and then reuse it ... For that I use selenium with python.

What I have done so far is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.olx.ro/oferta/vand-apartament-3-camere-2-dormitor-1-living-IDdJOij.html')
time.sleep(10)

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_class_name("spoiler")

time.sleep(12)
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

If on this page you click on "suna vanzatorul" the phone number of the seller will appear ... I would like to take this information ....

The item that should be clicked has the class:

contact-button link-phone {'path': 'phone', 'id': 'dcuxh', 'id_raw': '195069687'} atClickTracking contact-a

Unfortunately this is not static, it is dynamic and after the click this error appears:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":".contact-button link-phone"}   (Session info:
>   chrome=83.0.4103.97)

Please how could I extract that information from that website ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is with `xpath`:

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-rel='phone']")
inputElement.click()
```

Side note - consider using `WebDriverWait` instead of `time.sleep`.